# Compare 2 listview parent and child items and change image index

Tags: vb6

Listview1,Listview2 compare both parent and child items.
the items are named some-name.zip a-z and child files are loaded in each parent.

**Listview1 is Target**
**Listview2** is my loaded files i want to compare with Listview1
**image = 4** 'green icon
**image = 3** ' Red icon

Compare 2 listview and if it matches then listview2 image = 4 else image = 3
if child matches then image = 4 else image = 3

```
startt = True
Dim FoundIt As Boolean, ii As Integer, ix As Integer
Dim NodX As Node, NodX2 As Node
For Each NodX In TreeView1.Nodes
ix = NodX.Index
For Each NodX2 In TreeView2.Nodes
ii = NodX2.Index
If NodX.FullPath = NodX2.FullPath Then
FoundIt = True
On Error Resume Next
Exit For
End If
DoEvents
'pause 0
If TreeView2.Nodes(ii).Index = TreeView2.Nodes.Count - 0 Then
Exit For
Exit Sub
End If
Next
If FoundIt Then
TreeView1.Nodes(ix).Image = 4
TreeView2.Nodes(ii).Image = 4
Else
TreeView2.Nodes(ix).Image = 3
End If
If TreeView2.Nodes(ii).Index = TreeView2.Nodes.Count - 0 Then
DoEvents
'Call Command16_Click
If downnn = True Then
Exit For
Exit Sub
End If
End If
FoundIt = False
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you confirm the following: Go through every node and children in TreeView2 and check if there's a corresponding node in TreeView1. If there is, set Image = 4, otherwise Image = 3. I feel like we did this yesterday!

Comment: this code above works but its cheesy programming code,it does the job but greasy code not professional,the way you code it looks professional and it works smoothly

Comment: Some indentation in that code would help readability a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a Sub that takes in two TreeView controls and compares their contents. If a node in the Source TreeView doesn't have a corresponding node in the Target TreeView, its `Image`  gets set to 3. Otherwise, `Image` is set to 4:

```
Private Sub CompareTreeViews(ByRef p_objSourceTreeView As TreeView, ByRef p_objTargetTreeView As TreeView)
    Dim objSourceNode As Node
    Dim objTargetNode As Node
    Dim objMatchNode As Node
    Dim objSourceChildNode As Node
    Dim objTargetChildNode As Node
    Dim iSourceCounter As Integer
    Dim iTargetCounter As Integer
    Dim fFound As Boolean
    Dim fChildrenMatch As Boolean

    On Error Resume Next

    For Each objSourceNode In p_objSourceTreeView.Nodes

        ' Reset ChildrenMatch flag, used to track if all children match
        fChildrenMatch = True

        ' Find matching node in Source TreeView
        For Each objTargetNode In p_objTargetTreeView.Nodes

            If objTargetNode.Text = objSourceNode.Text Then
                ' Match found
                Set objMatchNode = objTargetNode
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        If Not objMatchNode Is Nothing Then

            ' Check all children
            If objSourceNode.Children > 0 Then

                ' Get first Child and Loop through all Children
                Set objSourceChildNode = objSourceNode.Child
                For iSourceCounter = 1 To objSourceNode.Children

                    ' Check if it exists in Target Treeview
                    If objMatchNode.Children > 0 Then

                        ' Set Found flag to False
                        fFound = False

                        ' Get first Child and Loop through all Children
                        Set objTargetChildNode = objMatchNode.Child
                        For iTargetCounter = 1 To objMatchNode.Children

                            ' Check for match
                            If objTargetChildNode.Text = objSourceChildNode.Text Then
                                fFound = True
                                Exit For
                            End If

                            ' Get next node
                            Set objTargetChildNode = objTargetChildNode.Next

                        Next

                        ' Mark Node
                        Select Case fFound
                            Case True
                                objSourceChildNode.Image = 4
                            Case False
                                objSourceChildNode.Image = 3
                                fChildrenMatch = False
                        End Select

                        ' Get next node
                        Set objSourceChildNode = objSourceChildNode.Next

                    End If

                    DoEvents

                Next ' Source Child

            End If

        End If

        Select Case fChildrenMatch
            Case True
                objSourceNode.Image = 4
            Case False
                objSourceNode.Image = 3
        End Select

        DoEvents

    Next ' Source Node

End Sub
```

Based on your question, you want to call the Sub this way:

```
Label1.Caption = "Comparing..."
CompareTreeViews TreeView2, TreeView1
Label1.Caption = "Done!"
```

Comment: Nice,I forgot to mention 2 things, if all child green then parent green image =4 or if child green and red then parent image = 3 and also add same image index's for Listview1. also if you can add a status to label1 process done so i know its finished ? i don't know how you do this but am gob-smacked

Comment: Added `fChildrenMatch` variable that tracks if all children match. Also, as far as displaying a status, you can do that before calling `CompareTreeViews` and after, as shown in answer.